# Is #define X defined(Y) a valid C/C++ macro definition?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I read somewhere that

```
#define X defined(Y)
```

was invalid, but it seems to work.

Here is an example:

```
#define WIN_PLAT defined(_WIN32)

#if WIN_PLAT
#    undef  WIN_PLAT
#    define WIN_PLAT 1
#else
#    undef  WIN_PLAT
#    define WIN_PLAT 0
#endif
```

Comment: Just no.  Everyone who writes cross-platform, portable code can recognize `#if defined(_WIN32)` instantly.  Don't screw that up by being cute.

Comment: What's wrong with `#if _WIN32` // `#define WIN_PLAT 1` // `#else` // `#define WIN_PLAT 0`

Comment: I did this because I have to handle different compilers and different platforms.

Comment: but now Im doing the "standard" way

Comment: The description "invalid" is very imprecise.   If a token `defined` is produced as a result of a macro expansion (which is what you are doing) then behaviour of the program is undefined.   Undefined behaviour is not required to be diagnosed and any behaviour your program exhibits is permitted.   So "seems to work" and "stops working during a blue moon" are equally correct behaviours according to the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a macro in a `#if` directive generates a `defined` token, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.10.1 4:

> … If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined…

Since the behavior is undefined, a compiler is free to support it, and a compiler is free not to support it. Therefore, you cannot rely on it generally.

To implement `#define X defined(Y)`, you can use:

```
#if defined Y
    #define X 1
#else
    #define X 0
#endif
```

(This differs from the original intent in that this will set `X` based on whether `Y` is defined at the point where this macro `X` is defined, not where it is replaced.)

C++ has the same limitation. C++ 2020 draft N4849 15.2 [cpp.cond] 10 says:

> … If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score -2):

Macros are text replacements, as long as you replace `defined(Y)` back into a preprocessor instruction it will work. It will however not work if you try to use it in C++ code:

```
cout << X; // error: undefined symbol 'defined'
```

Comment: Plus this is ugly as sin, and error prone. Surely you can do better!

Comment: For completeness, you should know that this will generate a warning in gcc (probably in the other compilers as well), turned off by default. You can certainly catch this during compilation if you want.

Comment: Macro processing works by token replacement, not text replacement. When macro replacement in a `#if` directive results in a `defined` token, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.10.1 4: “… If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you're not wrong, but note two things: 1. At the time I wrote this response, the tags were only C++, not C. 2. While all the major compilers do give a warning that it's not portable code, they will also compile it as expected. Unless you expect support for this to be dropped at some point (unlikely), we live in a world where this is de facto supported (like `#pragma once` was).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the statement by Blindy is correct, and you are too.  Macro processing is done by tokens (by C/C++ tokens) but, `defined` is a valid C/C++ token (an identifier).  It depends where the token is consumed to check for it's validity, as no one impedes you to declare a variable (or a funcion) named `defined`.  Token interpretation is anyway done at compilation time, not at preprocessing time.

Comment: @LuisColorado: The C and C++ standards **explicitly** state that if a macro replacement in a `#if` statement produce a `defined` token, the behavior is not defined by the standard. The assertion in this answer that it will work is not generally true.

Comment: A `defined` token is something that is interpreted inside a `cpp` directrive, but interpreted as an identifier by tthe compiler.  The standards (both in C/C++) say (as you remark) that how is it interpreted outside a macro expansion is undefined (it can be interpreted by the cpp or by the compiler itself)  so you have better not to play with it.  The PO only uses it inside a macro expansion text, so it can be expanded at macro definition, at macro expansion, or leave it out to the compiler.  This ambiguity is what is stated in the standard as undefined behaviour.  Correctly you are on your own

Comment: @LuisColorado: Re “The standards (both in C/C++) say (as you remark) that how is it interpreted outside a macro expansion is undefined”: No, that is not what I remark. `#if defined Y` is defined by the C standard, and here `defined` is used outside of a macro explansion. `#define X defined Y` followed by `#if X` is **not** defined by the C standard, and here `defined` is used in a macro expansion. The C standard says an implementation processing a `#if` directive does not have to process `defined` operators that result from macro expansion…

Comment: …  The C and C++ standards both explicitly state they do not define the behavior of trying to make a macro that has a `defined` operator in it and then using that macro in a `#if` directive.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that (what you say now) is what I meant to say.  IMHO we agree, so I don't completely follow you.  IMHO the rationale for this to be considered undefined (in the standard) is to not deal with the possible interpretations (all of them possibly valid, and not equivalent) that could lead to obscure and difficult to understand tricks in the production code.  But we both agree that both standards declare it undefined, so it's to be considered undefined, and you cannot build portable code based on this kind of construction.